# [GWT]Block the event of the browser in the case of link

Tags: gwt

I want to handle the event in the case of link by my own event listener.If we click on a link in browser, browser will open the address given in the link but i want to call my own event listener. I tried to do it in GWT by removing the attribute of the anchor tag which worked but it is not a clean solution. 
So if you are having any idea how to block the browser from opening that link please reply.

Answer (score 3):

In GWT **1.6** the correct code is:

```
ClickHandler foo = new ClickHandler() { 
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

        /// do your stuff

        event.stopPropagation(); // stops the event from bubbling to parent

        event.preventDefault();  // prevents the browsers default action,
                                 // following a link, etc
    }
}
```

This is roughly equivalent to:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that what this widget does:

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Hyperlink.html

eg: it looks like a normal hyperlink but lets you handle the onclick event?

Comment: This answer makes a good point. Look into GWT's History support, it may be exactly what you need.

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/History.html

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `event.cancel()` (GWT 1.6) or

```
Event.getCurrentEvent().cancelBubble(true);              // In 1.4 and earlier
DOM.eventCancelBubble(DOM.eventGetCurrentEvent(), true); // In 1.5
```

There is also a method to cancel an event from its instance within GWT 1.5, but I can't remember.